# jQuery how to removeClass of only certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a jQuery project where I'm looping through a list of elements that all have the same class. What I need is for the 1st two elements class to be removed. Therefore I'm using the .removeClass() method. However, I don't know how to use that method and only remove the 1st two. It's moving all of them. Can someone help me without changing the direction of my code.

```
function putSiblingsInTableForEachH2() {
        // line above sets function that will ultimately store siblings of each h2.toggler into a HTML table
        var togglerHeaders = $("h2.toggler");
        //  line above sets variable togglerHeaders to all h2 elements with a class of ".toggler"
        for (i = 0; i < togglerHeaders.length; i++) {
            // line above: for loop that loops through array "togglerHeaders"
            var currentH2Element = togglerHeaders[i];
            // line above sets variable currentH2Element to togglerHeaders at position i
            if (currentH2Element == togglerHeaders[0] || togglerHeaders[1]) {
                $("h2").removeClass("toggler");
            }
            var siblingsofH2 = $(currentH2Element).nextUntil("h2.toggler");
            // line above access siblings that are in h2.toggler element
            // line says: set variable "siblingsofH2" to the current h2.toggler element you're on actual sibling elements but only siblings that are in between current element and next element that is "h2.toggler"
            $(siblingsofH2).wrapAll("<table></table>");
            // line above says: after correct sibling elements are stored to variable siblingsofH2 wrap elements in HTML table
        } // line ends for loop 
    } // line ends function
    putSiblingsInTableForEachH2();
    // line above actually runs function
```

Comment: `currentH2Element == togglerHeaders[0] || togglerHeaders[1]` doesn’t mean the same thing as `currentH2Element == togglerHeaders[0] || currentH2Element == togglerHeaders[1]`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303160/if-statement-in-javascript-always-true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `$("h2").removeClass("toggler");`  will remove class from all, because it is referring to all.

I slightly edited your lines:

```js
if (i < 2) {
    $(currentH2Element).removeClass("toggler");
}
```

Comment: Thank you this answer made the most logical sense and was simple while not changing the direction of my original code.

Answer (score 1):

Plain JS `.querySelectorAll` with `:nth-child` formula

```
var firstTwo = document.querySelectorAll(".my-class:nth-child(-n+2)");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.

```js
var putThingsInTable = query => {
    
    var matches = document.querySelectorAll(query);
    if(!matches) return;
      var table = document.createElement('table')
      table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'))
     var i = 0;
     var toAdd = [];
     matches.forEach(match => {
        if(i > 1){
            toAdd.push(match);
        }
        i++
     });
     toAdd.forEach(element => {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(element);
        table.children[0].appendChild(td)
     });
     return table;
}
document.body.appendChild(putThingsInTable('h2.toggler'))
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="toggler">a</h2>
<h2 class="toggler">a</h2>
<h2 class="toggler">a</h2>
<h2 class="toggler">c</h2>
<h2 class="toggler">c</h2>
<h2 class="toggler">w</h2>
<h2 class="toggler">w</h2>
<h2 class="toggler">w</h2>
<h2 class="toggler">w</h2>
```

Comment: Sorry. I simply cannot stand jquery

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

This is the line of jQuery you are looking for ...

```
$("h2.toggler:gt(1)")
```

### Explanation

`:gt(1)` Will select all elements at an index greater than 1 within the matched set

See ... https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

### Example

For full example see ...

https://codepen.io/stephanieschellin/pen/MPdWVw

or ...

```js
$('h2.toggler:gt(1)').each(function(e) {
  $(this).nextUntil('h2').wrapAll('<table></table>')
})
```

```css
table {
  color: blue;
  border: solid 3px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="toggler">one</h2>
<span>one</span>
<span>one</span>


<h2 class="toggler">two</h2>
<span>two</span>
<span>two</span>


<h2 class="toggler">three</h2>
<span>three</span>
<span>three</span>
<span>three</span>


<h2 class="toggler">four</h2><span>four</span>
<span>four</span>
<span>four</span>

<h2 class="toggler">five</h2>
<span>five</span>
<span>five</span>
<span>five</span>
<span>five</span>

<h2 class="toggler">six</h2>
<span>six</span>
<span>six</span>
```